# django calculate total hour from datatimefield

Tags: django

I have a model that looks something like below which has a field called datetime. This field holds the record of date and time. What I want to do is to calculate the total number of hours per month and week. I need direction on how to go about doing that.

```html
class Clockin_Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    clockinusers = models.ForeignKey(Clockin_Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lid = models.IntegerField(db_column='LID', null=True, default=0)
    userid = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserID')
    temid = models.IntegerField(db_column='TemID')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateTime', help_text='eg:2021-07-21')
    inout = models.IntegerField(db_column='InOut') 
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.clockinusers.name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo could use something similar to this:

```
from datetime import datetime


end_date = datetime.today()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=7)



user = Clockin_Users.objects.filter(...)



transactions = Clockin_Transaction.objects.filter(
            clockinusers=user,
            datetime__range=[start_date, end_date],
        ).order_by('-datetime')

total = 0
for tr1, tr2 in zip(transactions, transactions[1:]):  # take every 2 consecutive transactions
    total += tr1.datetime - tr2.datetime

total = total / 3600  # convert from seconds to hours
```

Comment: Thanks, i try that but i got this error: DateTimeField Clockin_Transaction.datetime received a naive datetime (2021-10-06 23:14:36.692913) while time zone support is active.